# Copy JSON with multiple values from S3 to Redshift

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, copy, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to load a JSON file with multiple values in one of the columns to Redshift using the copy command but get an error:

> Invalid JSONPath format: Member is not an object.

This is how my JSON file looks like:

```
{"id":3,
"name":"John",
"children":[
{"child":"Ann","age":10},
{"child":"Dan","age":4},
{"child":"Ben","age":3}]
}
```

This is my jsonpath file:

```
{
    "jsonpaths": [
        "$.id",
        "$.name",
        "$.children.child",
        "$.children.age"
    ]
}
```

And I expect the data in the SQL to show:

```
id      name     child    age     
--      ----     -----    ---

3       John     Ann      10 

3       John     Dan      4

3       John     Ben      3
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSONPaths in COPY will only create one row per entry (or line) in your input file. In your example above, you want to create 3 lines from one entry, and Redshift doesn't support that.

You can consider preprocessing the data to convert it to something like this:

```
{
    "id":3,
    "name":"John",
    "child":"Ann",
    "age":10
},
{
    "id":3,
    "name":"John",
    "child":"Dan",
    "age":4
},
{
    "id":3,
    "name":"John",
    "child":"Ben",
    "age":3
}
```

And then, the following simple JSONPath will work:

```
{
    "jsonpaths": [
        "$.id",
        "$.name",
        "$.child",
        "$.age"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Our issue is that we are trying to load BSON collections from MongoDB to Redshift via S3 and we are struggling to do so. Since mongo dump only creates (nested) BSON files which we try to convert to JSON we get those brackets. Do you know of any best practice loading BSON files from S3 to Redshift with the copy command **not using an ETL tool** ?

Comment: It might be best to raise another question on that. As a quick answer, I'd try to write a bash/python script to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the structure of source file, try to load this to a PIVOT table with one column for each value (provided there are fixed number of values). Do an UNPIVOT in Redshift post the COPY process.